# Select distinct rows by multiple columns and retrieve yet another column which is not taking part in determining the distinctness

Tags: mysql, distinct

So here's how I select distinct rows by a combination of multiple columns (a, b and c):

```
select distinct a,b,c from my_table
```

This is good, but I need yet another column retrieved for these rows (d) which I can't add to the select part, because then it also plays a role in determining row uniqueness which I don't want.

How can I retrieve an additional column without it affecting row uniqueness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a group by.  In MySQL, you can do:

```
select a, b, c, d
from my_table
group by a, b, c
```

This chooses an arbitrary value for "d", which would typically (but not guanteed!) be the first value encountered.  This uses a feature of MySQL called Hidden Columns.

For code that works in MySQL and other databases, you need to be more explicit:

```
select a, b, c, min(d)
from my_table
group by a, b, c
```

Getting an actual random value for d in MySQL is a bit trickier and requires more work.  Here is one way:

```
select distinct a, b, c,
       (select d from my_table mt2
        where mt.a = mt2.a and mt.b = mt2.b and mt.c = mt2.c
        order by rand()
        limit 1
       ) d
from my_table mt
```

Comment: I  was thinking about group by, but I think it is not equivalent to distinct with multpile columns, is it? Group by a,b,c collapses the result set first by a, then by b and then by c if I understand it correctly and it does not give the same result as distinct if a is not the most unique column in the trio, because then collapsing by a destroys uniqueness in other columns. Is it not the case?

Comment: Group by and distinct do the same thing on the columns in the group by statement.  Neither guarantee the order of the results and both will return exactly the same rows.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for a join... probably a `LEFT JOIN`. Something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT L.a, L.b, L.c FROM `my_table` L
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT a, b, c, d FROM `my_table`
) R ON L.a=R.a AND L.b=R.b AND L.c=R.c
```